# date default timezone set problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the function

`$data=date_default_timezone_set("Y-m-d");`

and I'm getting the date like 0000-00-00 in my table. Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_default_timezone_set` sets the default timezone and takes time zone identifier(e.g. "EST" or "EST5EDT").
After time zone is set you can use `date` function to format datetime value.

```
date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); // timezone you want to use if you don't want the OS default timezone
$dt = date("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that you are providing a date format, not time zone? Proper argument would be in example "Europe/Prague", what you probably want is date() function

Answer (score 0):

[`date_default_timezone_set`](http://pt.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) receives a timezone identifier, not a date formatter.

You probably want something like `date("Y-m-d")`.

Answer (score 0):

[date-default-timezone-set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is used for setting a deafult timezone (like "Europe/Moscow"), not for setting date format. You might need to use "date('Y-m-d');"

Answer (score 0):

`date_default_timezone_set()` is used to set the default timezone used by date and time functions.

Calling the function as `$data=date_default_timezone_set("Y-m-d")` is wrong for two reasons:

- The return value of the function is `TRUE` when the passed parameter is a valid timezone identifier, and `FALSE` when it's not a valid identifier.
- The identifier you are using is not valid; it should be something like `'America/New_York'`.